# Добавить нули в начало строки

Tags: sql, sqlite

Есть запрос:

```
select f14,
       replace(sum(replace(f14,'+-','-')),'.0','')
from Table
where f1=602
group by f14;
```

f14 имеет числа в формате : `+-0000008334`
после запроса я получаю число в формате `-16668`

Как можно добавить нули в получившемся числе если в поле всегда 10 цифр и один знак в начале `+/-`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    f14,
    printf("%011d",sum(replace(f14,'+-','-'))) 
from 
    Table 
where 
    f1=602
group by 
    f14;
```

[printf(FORMAT,...)](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#printf)

> The printf(FORMAT,...) SQL function works like the sqlite3_mprintf()
>   C-language function and the printf() function from the standard C
>   library. The first argument is a format string that specifies how to
>   construct the output string using values taken from subsequent
>   arguments. If the FORMAT argument is missing or NULL then the result
>   is NULL. The %n format is silently ignored and does not consume an
>   argument. The %p format is an alias for %X. The %z format is
>   interchangeable with %s. If there are too few arguments in the
>   argument list, missing arguments are assumed to have a NULL value,
>   which is translated into 0 or 0.0 for numeric formats or an empty
>   string for %s.

Comment: То, что нужно, спасибо.